# What does "cry fie" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I read this sentence from [here](http://www.literaturepage.com/read/vanity-fair-746.html)-

> *.... has any the most squeamish immoralist in Vanity Fair a right to cry fie?*

What does "cry fie" mean?

Comment: Think of it as *...cry "Fie!"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic firstly because it is about an archaic usage, and secondly because the entire citation seems to be from a non-native speaker (it's not even *remotely* grammatical).

Comment: ...okay, I see it's William Makepeace Thackeray. It's still not English such as would be recognised today, if indeed it even was when he wrote it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is obsolete language, but you can work out what it means by looking up *cry* and *fie* in the dictionary:

> **fie** exclamation (archaic)
>
> 1: used to express disgust or outrage.
>
> "if people don't answer your first letter, fie on them!"
>
> **cry** v.
>
> 2: shout or scream, esp. to express one's fear, pain, or grief.
>
> "the little girl fell down and cried for her mommy"
>
> synonyms:   call, shout, exclaim, sing out, yell, shriek, scream, screech, bawl, bellow, roar, vociferate, squeal, yelp, holler;
>
> antonyms:   whisper

Consequently we can deduce that to "cry fie" is an archaic term meaning "to shout an expression of disgust or outrage".